# Java integration testing (DAO layer, generic CRUD operations)

Tags: spring, hibernate, testing, junit

I have been looking for a refined way to create integration tests for DAO layer (Java, Spring, Hibernate), mostly for generic CRUD operations (readAll(), getById(), insert(), update(), delete(). etc.), for several months. What I've found so far is either 1) too laborious approach with the amount of code comparable with real source code or 2) Too complicated/unreadable/inflexible approach to do it.
One attempt that I've undertaken so far is the following:
If we have say generic DAO interface like this one:

```
public interface GenericDAO<T> {
    Long insert(T t);
    void update(T t);
    List<T> getAll();
    T getById(Long id);
    void delete(T t);
 }
```

Then we could propose some template method (because all the tests are performed randomly by default) to perform all those CRUD operations, which is applicable to every class:

```
@Transactional
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/test-context.xml"})
public abstract class AbstractDAOTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
            insert();
            read();
            readAll();
            update();
            delete();
    }

    protected abstract void insert();

    protected abstract void read();

    protected abstract void readAll();

    protected abstract void update();

    protected abstract void delete();
```

}

Then we have Spring's test config with sample data and implement all these methods in real class-successor.

This is still not nice to me. (only one actual method to test, time-consuming to create test-context, etc.)

So, what is the most recognisible and triend-and-true approcah to create integration tests for DAO layer? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know if you are in Spring 4.3, but they've done a considerable work on (integration) testing for that release. You could look at https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html

Comment: Yes, thank you, I've seen it. What I am wondering if there has been an approach proven to be used in enterprise applications ( as I know enterprise only relies on trusted frameworks, not up-to-date ones). Surely I will explore it further!

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure Spring 4.3 is already being used in production entreprise applications ; however, it was just a comment and not even trying to answer your question, hope you'll have better luck.